# find all files indirectory and sub-directories and provide the path from directory

Tags: python

Hi I want to find all files in a folder including all files in the sub-folders. This is my code

```
all_files = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        all_files.append(os.path.join(path, name))
print "all_files2 = ", all_files
```

however the code above gives me all files with the entire path. I want all files with the path from root. So if the file is in root, I just want the the filename, if it is in the subdirectory root/images I want images/filename..
thanks carl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change:

```
all_files.append(os.path.join(path, name))
```

to:

```
all_files.append(os.path.join(path[len(root):], name))
```

to slice the current path starting at how long root is. ie:

```
>>> root = 'hello'
>>> sub = 'hello is is ew'
>>> sub[:len(root)]
'hello'
>>> sub[len(root):]
' is is ew'
```

you can also use `relpath()`

```
>>> os.path.relpath('root/image/thistoo','root')
'image\\thistoo'
```

so:

```
all_files.append(os.path.join(os.path.relpath(path,root), name))
```

Comment: @Pynchia i beg to differ, all of python `strip` methods read the parameters as a list of chars so it would strip all instances of those chars from the beginning of the string. ie if you call `'root/hey/heyo/rooted'.lstrip('root/hey')` you will get return value of `'d'`